# Retrieving files from all subfolders using SFTP adapter in Biztalk

Tags: file, adapter, sftp, biztalk, subdirectory

I need to get all .pdf files from a large amount of subfolders located in a single folder. New subfolders are constant created, each containing a set of .pdf files.

I would like to avoid creating a new receive location for each folder. And since new subfolders are always created, this option is not possible.

Is it possible using the SFTP adapter to scan a folder for subfolders and the files within them? I haven't been able to accomplish this using the standard SFTP adapter, or even the FILE adapter. Would I need to create a custom adapter for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible using the OOB SFTP Adapter.

A common way to address this scenario is to use a Scheduled Task/Agent Job using another SFTP client to pull the files recursively onto a file share where they can be read by the BizTalk app.

If you're using BizTalk Server 2016, you already have WinSCP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I am in the process of creating a script for WinSCP that moves the files from the subfolders into a single folder.